# How can i compare between two LiveData values in kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

In this picture i have an error with the 'greater than' , i have two LiveData values **_adder.value** and **_quantity.value**, i want to compare between them.

Here's a **[screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LfedB.png)**
and Here's the [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/428ZA.png)

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because you should not use screenshots for posting code

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please refer to the guide on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and when needed, how to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so people can try to help you with a problem. You're often expected to do your own homework and research before asking a question, and not include screenshots as code.

Comment: I'm new to the site so i don't know what and what not to do, Thank you all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The live data values are nullables, so you can't do that comparison. From the androidX LiveData java class:

```
    @Nullable
    public T getValue() {
        Object data = mData;
        if (data != NOT_SET) {
            return (T) data;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

The `@Nullable` annotation tells Kotlin that has to make the value nullable. That is why the errors says

```
Required Int
Found Int?
```

```
val adderValue = _adder.value //this is nullable
val quantityValue = _quantity.value //this is nullable
```

For fixing your problem you have to decide what to do with `null`.

If you want that null to be equivalent to zero, then:

```
_adder.value ?: 0 < _quantity.value ?: 0
```

Or if is null, then nothing should happen, then:

```
val adderValue = _adder.value ?: return
val quantityValue = _quantity.value ?: return
if (adderValue < quantityValue)
```

Since you are adding a cupcake I speculate what you want is the following:

```
val adderValue = _adder.value ?: 0 //no additions before so is ok
val quantityValue = _quantity.value ?: return //null quantity is not ok, error we stop
if (adderValue < quantityValue) {
    _adder.value = adderValue++
}
```

What you are doing there `_adder.value?.plus(1)` is not updating the live data value.

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin's equality operators (== and !=) can handle nulls, while the order comparison operators (<, <=, >, >=) can't.

You have to check the nullability before doing the comparison.

You may also use another value if the live data is null (like 0) using the Elvis operator, but I won't suggest this solution, because the *null* value is not the same as the *zero* value.